# Whitespace not caught by Laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I'm trying to validate a password input field, and spaces are not getting caught by the validator. The password field should be a minimum of 6 characters, and the regex should allow spaces within a password, but not at the beginning or end (I've confirmed that this works outside of the validator).

When a user enters in 1+ spaces into the password field (but no other characters) and submits, the validator fails to catch it (i.e., "    " isn't caught by the validator).

Here's what my validator looks like:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255|alpha',
    'password' => 'regex:/^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$/|min:6|confirmed',
]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The validator checks if the input [isValidatable()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/806fcea5902d4421a387570edd461782252b10ed/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L601) by [trimming the input](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/806fcea5902d4421a387570edd461782252b10ed/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L617), and determining if the input is empty, and despite it's emptiness, if that input should still be validated (i.e., inputs with rules such as required, present, etc are determined to be validatable and are dealt with later on in the validation process).

In this case, since none of these [implicit rules](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/806fcea5902d4421a387570edd461782252b10ed/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L164) were included in the field validation rules, the whitespace input was determined to be not validatable, and never reached the regex or min rules.

HT to jemaclus for digging around and discovering this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in you regex. After the second \s should go * not +. Use the following one:

```
/^[^\s]+(\s*[^\s]+)*$/
```

Validator may not work if other rules used together with regex and they are separated with pipelines. So try to use array of rules:

`'password' => array('regex:/^[^\s]+(\s*[^\s]+)*$/', 'min:6', 'confirmed'`)

Comment: Thanks for the help Andrej. I'm not a regex master (just took the regex I used from another question) however both yours and mine seems to do the same thing (either way the validator still doesn't catch the spaces and throw an error).

Comment: @DanielRHarris what string doesn't pass validation?

Comment: The problem is that it IS passing validation: "     " (i.e., all spaces)

Comment: No change, still allows all spaces.

Comment: Can you post the whole action from controller? @DanielRHarris

Answer (score 0):

i tested in a test laravel app with this and it seemed to work

`'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed|regex:/^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$/',`

Comment: If you add required it works (because the validator seems to trim the input, and then the required fails because it's blank), but this is for a password update field on a profile edit page, if they leave it blank, I want it to just not update their password. HT jemaclus -- it seems that the validator simply ignores all whitespace strings... so it's not even reaching the regex or min.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore using Regex at all, simply like this

```
'password'=>[
            'required',
            'min:6',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail){
                if (strstr($value,' ')) {
                    $fail(__('site.no_whitespaces_allowed_in_password'));
                }
            },
        ],
        'password_confirmation'=>[
            'required',
            'min:6',
            'same:password',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail){
                if (strstr($value,' ')) {
                    $fail(__('site.no_whitespaces_allowed_in_password_confirmation'));
                }
            },
        ],
```